Azure SDK for CPP DownloadTo function very slow
I've integrated Azure SDK for CPP in my application, and there is significant slow down compared to old Azure SDK.
After upgrade for Upload Azure-sdk-for-cpp parallelism, upload works better, but download is still VERY SLOW.
It can be reproduced with simple example, just by trying to download 1Gb file from Azure storage to local file system.

Old SDK ~1min
New SDK ~5min

Old SDK was using CPP REST which used concurrency::streams::istream m_stream; There is no such thing in new SDK , except for TransferOptions.Concurrency which does almost nothing.
Is there some idea how can DownloadTo can be speed up? Or should parallelism be implemented on top of the library?
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

#include <azure/storage/blobs.hpp>

#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string GetConnectionString()
{
  const static std::string ConnectionString = "";

  if (!ConnectionString.empty())
  {
    return ConnectionString;
  }
  const static std::string envConnectionString = std::getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
  if (!envConnectionString.empty())
  {
    return envConnectionString;
  }
  throw std::runtime_error("Cannot find connection string.");
}

int main()
{
  using namespace Azure::Storage::Blobs;

  const std::string containerName = "sample-container";
  const std::string blobName = "sample-blob";
  const std::string blobContent = "Hello Azure!";

  auto containerClient
      = BlobContainerClient::CreateFromConnectionString(GetConnectionString(), containerName);

  containerClient.CreateIfNotExists();

  BlockBlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);

  std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(blobContent.begin(), blobContent.end());
  blobClient.UploadFrom(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

  Azure::Storage::Metadata blobMetadata = {{"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "value2"}};
  blobClient.SetMetadata(blobMetadata);

  auto properties = blobClient.GetProperties().Value;
  for (auto metadata : properties.Metadata)
  {
    std::cout << metadata.first << ":" << metadata.second << std::endl;
  }
  // We know blob size is small, so it's safe to cast here.
  buffer.resize(static_cast<size_t>(properties.BlobSize));

  blobClient.DownloadTo(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

  std::cout << std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end()) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}


This seems like excellent feedback for the folks working on the C++ package, who are also best positioned to offer suggestions to help mitigate in the meantime.   I'd encourage you to open an issue in the Azure SDK for C++ repository: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp/issues

Thanks you for the suggestion, I will do it for sure. I think it's quite a problem.

@JohnDoe Check the below answer.

Long story short, CACHING was the solution. Our system is designed such way, that read function always read only 32kb, and then you can imagine the amount of http requests... At first I have tried to download a 1gb locally and then whenever read is called, get a chunk of that 1gb, afterwards I reduced it all way to 4mb, which showed great results. Speed up was insane.


Is there some idea how can DownloadTo can be speed up? Or should parallelism be implemented on top of the library?.

I would recommend to go with split your download into chunks and parallelize them manually. This approach resembles the method used by some HTTP clients to download files in parallel.
You can use the below code to download much faster using C++ SDK.
Code:
#include <azure/storage/blobs.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    using namespace Azure::Storage::Blobs;

    const std::string containerName = "result";
    const std::string blobName = "test.mp4";
    const std::string outputFileName = "demo1.mp4"; // Output file

    auto containerClient = BlobContainerClient::CreateFromConnectionString("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=venkat326123;AccountKey=redacted;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", containerName);
    containerClient.CreateIfNotExists();

    BlockBlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    auto properties = blobClient.GetProperties().Value;
    size_t blobSize = static_cast<size_t>(properties.BlobSize);

    const size_t chunkSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
    size_t totalChunks = (blobSize + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize; 

    std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName, std::ios::binary);
    if (!outputFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open output file: " << outputFileName << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::mutex fileMutex;

    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Start downloading each chunk in parallel
    for (size_t i = 0; i < totalChunks; ++i)
    {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&, i]()
            {
                try
                {
                    // Calculate start and length for each chunk
                    size_t start = i * chunkSize;
                    size_t length = std::min(chunkSize, blobSize - start);

                    // Define download options with range for each chunk
                    Azure::Storage::Blobs::DownloadBlobToOptions rangeOptions;
                    rangeOptions.Range = Azure::Core::Http::HttpRange{ static_cast<int64_t>(start), static_cast<int64_t>(length) };

                    // Temporary buffer for chunk
                    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(length);

                    // Download chunk data into the temporary buffer
                    blobClient.DownloadTo(buffer.data(), length, rangeOptions);

                    // Lock and write the buffer to the file at the correct position
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(fileMutex);
                    outputFile.seekp(start);
                    outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), length);
                }
                catch (const std::exception& e)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error downloading chunk " << i << ": " << e.what() << std::endl;
                }
            }));
    }

    // Wait for all chunks to finish downloading
    for (auto& f : futures)
    {
        f.get();
    }

    // Stop timing the download
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Close the file stream
    outputFile.close();

    // Calculate time taken in seconds
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsedSeconds = end - start;

    // Calculate download speed in MBps
    double downloadSpeed = (blobSize / (1024.0 * 1024.0)) / elapsedSeconds.count();

    std::cout << "Downloaded blob '" << blobName << "' to file '" << outputFileName << "' of size " << blobSize << " bytes." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time taken: " << elapsedSeconds.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Download speed: " << downloadSpeed << " MBps" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The above code divides the file into 4 MB chunks and downloads them concurrently using std::async for efficient multi-threading, ensuring thread-safe writing with std::mutex.
Output:
Downloaded blob 'test.mp4' to file 'demo1.mp4' of size 69632912 bytes.
Time taken: 15.3713 seconds
Download speed: 4.32019 MBps


File:

Also check with the GitHub link which your created they can also provide good suggestions to help with C++ SDK.

Indeed this works, but not for my use case :/ Whenever I download chunk I have to pass it to the upper layer. But thanks anyway for suggestion, I will try to refactor it to work for my situation

Yeah, this is the possible way to download faster.

I've checked old implementation and then were using open_read function, which opened stream for downloading. and there is no such thing in new SDK :/

Yes I researched on that:(

Interesting, I have tried to download whole blob at once, it is very fast, but unfortunately when it has to be downloaded in pieces then the performance drastically drops down

Any updates is the issue resolved?

not yet. I will update here as soon as they give me feedback.

I'm being totally ignored on github :/ Hopefully they will have some update soon.

Looks like I've found a solution. It was kind of obvious and right in front of the nose all the time... I completely ignored chunk sizes, and after I saw they are 32kb I realised they are too small. So what I have done to not break existing architecture, I just added local buffer where I download at least 4mb chunk into buffer, and then I read from it. After the buffer is empty, I download new chunk. It improved speed quite a lot.

@JohnDoe It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community and accept it

Sorry for the long wait. Long story short, CACHING was the solution. Our system is designed such way, that read function always read only 32kb, and then you can imagine the amount of http requests... At first I have tried to download a 1gb locally and then whenever read is called, get a chunk of that 1gb, afterwards I reduced it all way to 4mb, which showed great results. Speed up was insane.

done. Thanks for the always helping!!!
